# Transactional table and Reporting table within same database

Tags: database

I did read posts about transactional and reporting database.
We have in single  table which is used for reporting(historical) purpose and transactional
eg :order with fields
orderid, ordername, orderdesc, datereceived, dateupdated, confirmOrder

Is it a good idea to split this table into neworder and orderhistrory
The new ordertable records the current days transaction (select,insert and update activity every ms for the orders  received on that day .Later we merge this table with order history

Is this a recommended approach.
Do you think this is would minimize the load and processing time on the Database?

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL supports basic table partitioning which allows  splitting what is logically one large table into smaller physical pieces. [More info provided here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/ddl-partitioning.html).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question: No.  Moving data from one place to another is an extra load that you otherwise wouldn't have if you used the transational table for reporting.  But there are some other questions you need to ask before you make this decision.

1. **How often are these reports run?**
   If you are running these reports once an hour, it may make sense to keep them in the same table.  However, if this report takes a while to run, you'll need to take care not to tie up resources for the other clients using it as a transactional table.
2. **How up-to-date do these reports need to be?**
   If the reports are run less than daily or weekly, it may not be critical to have up to the minute data in the reports.

And this is where the reporting table comes in.  The approaches I've seen typically involve having a "data warehouse," whether that be implemented as a single table or an entire database.  This warehouse is filled on a schedule with the data from the transactional table, which subsequently triggers the generation of a report.  This seems to be the approach you are suggesting, and is a completely valid one.  Ultimately, the one question you need to answer is *when* you want your server to handle the load.  If this can be done on a schedule during non-peak hours, I'd say go for it.  If it needs to be run at any given time, than you may want to keep the single-table approach.

Of course there is nothing saying you can't do both.  I've seen a few systems that have small on-demand reports run on transactional tables, scheduled warehousing of historical data, and then long-running reports against that historical data.  It's really just a matter of how real-time you want the data to be.